# Не работает библиотека OS python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ос, syntax

Импортирую os и написал действие, но выдает непонятную мне ошибку, можете посоветовать как убрать ошибку? Использую Visual studio code

```
import os
os.system('C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или слеш добавить, или букву  r `os.system(r'C:/Windows/system32/cmd.exe')`

Comment: Не помогло. Та же ошибка

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, вы выполняли в интерактивной консоли питона команду, предназначенную для запуска в терминале

Comment: То есть нужно запустить файл с этим кодом? Через cmd

Comment: Такое впечатление, что сам питон запускается со знаком `&` впереди. Надо проверять, как VS Code вообще питон то запускает

Comment: Не работает именно этот код. Все остальное запускается хорошо

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8

����� ����⠬� � 8.8.8.8 �� � 32 ���⠬� ������:
�⢥� �� 8.8.8.8: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=32�� TTL=107
�⢥� �� 8.8.8.8: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=32�� TTL=107
�⢥� �� 8.8.8.8: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=33�� TTL=107
�⢥� �� 8.8.8.8: �᫮ ����=32 �६�=32�� TTL=107
` Все работает только кодировка не совпадает, проверяйте у себя

Comment: А какая необходима кодировка? У меня стоит UTF-8

Comment: А какая задача стоит?  Вопрос `Не работает библиотека OS python` - ответ все работает.

Comment: Код должен открывать командную строку, но выдает ошибку, из за чего она я пока что не понимаю. Есть способ исправить ее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для запуска cmd предлагаю использовать

```
import os
os.startfile(r'c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe')
```

но какой смысл запускать shell?